# gem mongo 1.6.2 returns wrong value on count (Cursor)

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rubygems

I'm using the following code to fetch something from mongo:

```
class BlockingMongoFetcher
  include MongoConfig

  def initialize
    configure
    @connection = Mongo::Connection.new(@server, @port)
    @collection = init_collection(@connection)
  end

  def fetch(value)
    mongo_cursor = @collection.find({ KEY => value.to_s })

    if mongo_cursor.count == 0
      # do stuff
      return nil
    end

    if mongo_cursor.count > 1
      # do stuff
    end

    mongo_cursor.first
  end
end
```

init_collection just gets the db and the collection object from the connection.
In the fetch method, I'm using the count method to check, if there are results. Since I got a 0, where there should be 1 item, I added the following code within the gem to the count method of the Cursor class:

```
if response['n'].to_i == 0
  require "ruby-debug"
  debugger
  puts "stop here"
end
```

( response = @db.command(command) )

Within the debugger

```
@db.command(command)['n'].to_i
```

returns 1. If I call count in the fetch method twice (once without using the output) everything is fine. Am I missing something? Buffer or caching problem? However, this seems not to be deterministic ... it only occurs in about 50 % of the runs. Mongodb is 2.0.2 and Ruby 1.9.3p125.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: in your question, you talk about using `count`, but that doesn't even appear in your code… Please try to construct a minimal example where your problem arises so that people can understand your problem and find solutions to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mhh, unexpected solution:

For inserting test data, I used the following statement within the spec

```
collection.insert @hash
```

The insert method has an option :safe, see the [API](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.6.2/Mongo/Collection.html#insert-instance_method). With the default (false), mongodb stores it async and the code execution continues. This can lead to strange behavior, like the value is not yet in the db, if you query it instantly afterwards. Just use

```
collection.insert @hash, :safe => true
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have an error somewhere and suggest that you check the results of your cursor query (ex., p collection.find(query).to_a) versus the collection(ex. p collection.find.to_a).  The following works for me with Ruby 1.9.3, Mongo 2.0.4, mongo-ruby-driver 1.6.2.  I hope that it helps, maybe you can verify that it works for you as well and can converge on a solution.

MongoConfig.rb

```
require "mongo"

KEY = 'my_key'

module MongoConfig
  SERVER = 'localhost'
  PORT = Mongo::Connection::DEFAULT_PORT
  DB = 'my_db'
  COLLECTION = 'my_collection'

  attr_accessor :db, :collection

  def configure
    @server = SERVER
    @port = PORT
  end

  def init_collection(connection)
    @db = connection[MongoConfig::DB]
    @collection = @db[MongoConfig::COLLECTION]
    return @collection
  end

end
```

blocking_mongo_fetcher_test.rb

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.expand_path("..", __FILE__))

require "test-unit"
require "MongoConfig"
require "BlockingMongoFetcher"

class BlockingMongoFetcherTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    clear_collection
  end

  def clear_collection
    Mongo::Connection.new[MongoConfig::DB][MongoConfig::COLLECTION].remove
  end

  def count_various_ways_and_cursor_twice_test
    value = 'my name'
    query = {KEY => value}
    count_command = {'count' => MongoConfig::COLLECTION, 'query' => { KEY => value} }
    fetcher = BlockingMongoFetcher.new

    assert_equal(0, fetcher.collection.count) # collection count
    assert_equal(0, fetcher.collection.find(query).count) # cursor count
    assert_equal(0, fetcher.db.command(count_command)['n'].to_i) # db command count
    assert_nil(fetcher.fetch(value))

    fetcher.collection.insert({KEY => value})
    fetcher.collection.insert({KEY => 'x'})

    assert_equal(2, fetcher.collection.count) # collection count
    assert_equal(1, fetcher.collection.find(query).count) # cursor count
    assert_equal(1, fetcher.db.command(count_command)['n'].to_i) # db command count
    assert_equal(value, fetcher.fetch(value)[KEY])

    cursor = fetcher.collection.find(query)
    assert_equal(1, cursor.count) # check once
    assert_equal(1, cursor.count) # check twice
  end

  test "basic test" do
    count_various_ways_and_cursor_twice_test
  end

  test "repeated test" do
    100.times do
      clear_collection
      count_various_ways_and_cursor_twice_test
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thx Gary, you're right. I could manage to run a similiar test like yours. Then it must be a problem with the testing environment that I have. Should have mentioned this before ... The code is running in rspec with spork and some other libs. I'm going to check this direction and update (or answer :-) ) the question.